# Insert Date into MS Access vba Query

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, insert

I'm trying to insert the current date into a table using VBA in MS Acess.  The date gets inserted as 12/30/1899  No matter what I try.  Any advise to fix this?  Here is my code

```
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim InID As Integer
Dim Inputcasedate As String
Dim InputCaseType_Id As Integer

InID = Me.PgmPart_ID
Inputcasedate = Date
InputCaseType_Id = 1

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO CaseNotes (PgmPart_ID,CaseType_ID,CaseDate) " & _
     "VALUES (" & InID & "," & InputCaseType_Id & "," & Inputcasedate & ")"
```

Answer (score 2):

In MS Access, literal date values must be delimited by pound/numeral/hashtag symbols: `#`.

```vb
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO CaseNotes (PgmPart_ID,CaseType_ID,CaseDate) " & _
         "VALUES (" & InID & ", " & InputCaseType_Id & ", #" & Inputcasedate & "#)"
```

However, like VBA, Access SQL maintains the `Date()` function. So use this expression *inside* the SQL statement and avoid the concatenated VBA variable.

```vb
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO CaseNotes (PgmPart_ID,CaseType_ID,CaseDate) " & _
         "VALUES (" & InID & ", " & InputCaseType_Id & ", Date())"
```

---

However, consider the industry best practice with [parameterized SQL](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) which MS Access's DAO supports via [QueryDefs.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). Doing so, requires no value delimiters like quotes for strings or numerals for dates and aligns data types between app layer (VBA) and database.

```vb
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim qdef As QueryDef

' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO VBA VARIABLES)
StrSQL = "PARAMETERS ParamInID Long, ParamInputCaseType_Id Long; " & _
         "INSERT INTO CaseNotes (PgmPart_ID, CaseType_ID, CaseDate) " & _
         "VALUES (ParamInID, ParamInputCaseType_Id, Date());"

' INITIALIZE DAO OBJECTS
Set db = CurrentDb
qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", StrSQL)

' BIND PARAMETERS
qdef!ParamInID = Me.PgmPart_ID
qdef!ParamInputCaseType_Id = 1

' EXECUTE ACTION
qdef.Execute

Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Then also please mark as _answered_.